# PHP ARRAY, there are many times the same valu inside

Tags: php, arrays, csv, duplicates

I am trying to use a csv file in my php code. I tried this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("licences/myFile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
  $num = count($handle);
  $row++;
    for ($cc=0; $cc < $num; $cc++) {
      $UserLine = explode(";",trim($data[$cc]));
      $Users =$UserLine[$cc];
      echo "</br>" . print_r($UserLine) . "</br>";
    }
  }
}
```

But the output is not what I expect. I get this when I do the print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => GL [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => papb1 [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => RES [1] => )
1
Array ( [0] => ecllit [1] => )
1
```

It's repeating the values again and again.

The content of "myFile.csv" is:

```
GL;
papb1;
RES;
ecllit;
```

And my variable $users as the value:

```
GLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllitGLpapb1RESecllit
```

Can someone help me to only have the values one time, if it's not in the array at least in $users. Because I have a lot of users to add in the csv, but I want this step to work before writing all the users.

Sorry if it's a basic question or if I haven't given enough informations or if this is not clear, this is my first post :/

Thanks for any future replies,

Sellion

Comment: you should use count($data) instead of $count($handle)

Comment: @Schäbo Thank you for your reply. I tried to change this but it doesn't change de output from the print_r

Comment: If you use `fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';')` you don't have to do the explode, [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) will do it for you and return the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this updated.

Your csv file needs to be something like this.

```
GL
papb1
RES
ecllit
```

Then use the updated code as below.

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    $line = 1;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) 
    { 
        echo "Line # $line : " . $data[0] . "</br>";
        $line++;
    }
}
```

This will give you output like below :

```
Line # 1 : GL
Line # 2 : papb1
Line # 3 : RES
Line # 4 : ecllit
```

I hope that is something you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are right, this is easier than my solution, but I get the same output from the print_r($data);

Comment: What is the output you are expecting ? If you are expecting values do not use ";" as the delimiter. PHP will automatically detect new line characters as the delimiter while fetching a line. I am updating my code.

Comment: your code was very helpful, I have what I want now. Thank you.